# Problema con el footer usando bootstrap 3.3.7

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5, bootstrap

**Hola!!**estoy haciendo una pagina web con HTML 5, CSS3 y Bootstrap 3.3.7....Esta pagina tiene una barra de navegación y un contenedor al lado izquierdo, hasta el momento todo va bien pero el problema se da en la etiqueta footer... Resulta de que aparece a la mitad de la pagina (que es hasta ahí en donde tengo el contenido).[image]

Como ven en la imagen, el footer aparece atravesado en la mitad de la pagina y en realidad quiero que el footer este siempre abajo sin importar la cantidad de contenido que se encuentre en la pagina. He probado muchas soluciones que he encontrado pero ninguna me ha solucionado el problema. Algo curioso que pasa es que si quito el link del css de Bootstrap el footer toma su lugar, es decir se coloca abajo...
Esto queda con sin el css de Bootstrap...
[image]
Como ven así queda cuando se quita el css de bootstrap.

Este es el código fuente....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Lllamado a las hojas de estilos CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../CSS/Bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../CSS/Administrador.css">
    <title>Administración</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Barra del menú -->
<header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class=" navbar navbar-default nav navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-1">
                        <span class="sr-only"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <img class="Imagen"src="../Imagenes/LOGO.png" alt="FYDBB">
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="">Empresa</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="">Ofertas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Ver Registros</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Cotizar</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                Seguridad
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="">Usuarios</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Roles</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                Productos
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                               <li><a href="#">Familia#1</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">Familia#2</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">Familia#3</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">Familia#4</a></li>
                               <li class="divider"></li>
                               <li><a href="">Ver Productos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar artículo">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                            Ayuda
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Versión</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Ayuda</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                Cuenta
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                               <li><a href="">Ajustes</a></li>
                               <li><a href="">Cambiar contraseña</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<!-- Termina la barra del menú -->
<!-- Mensaje de bienvenida al usuario -->
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="container" id="Mensaje">
        <h1>Administración de la página</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Cuerpo de la pagina -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <br>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <h3 class="list-group-item active">
                    Acciones
                    </h3>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        Dapibus ac facilisis in
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        Morbi leo risus
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        Porta ac consectetur ac
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        Vestibulum at eros
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="fixed-bottom">

  <!-- Copyright -->
  <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2018 Copyright:
    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Copyright -->

</footer>
<!-- Footer -->
</body>
<!-- Sciripts para el uso de JQuery y Bootstrap -->
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</html>
```

Este es el CSS:

```
  body{
    padding-top: 80px;
    background: url(../Imagenes/LOGO.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 450px;
}
#Mensaje{
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.Imagen{
    width: 220px;
}  
footer{
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Espero que haya dado a entender y que me puedan ayudar, se los agradezco!!!

Answer (score 1):

Cambia el atributo `height` del elemento que consideras como "cuerpo" en tu HTML, esto con el motivo de que empuje los elementos que se encuentren debajo como el `footer`.

**En tu CSS:**

...

```
.cuerpo
{
    height:100vh; /*puedes ajustarlo según la altura que necesites*/
}
```

**En tu HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Barra del menú -->
<header>
   ....
</header>
<!-- Termina la barra del menú -->
<!-- Mensaje de bienvenida al usuario -->
<div class="row-fluid">
    ...
</div>
<!-- Cuerpo de la pagina -->
<!-- agregas la clase 'cuerpo' para ajustar la altura -->
    <div class="cuerpo container-fluid">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    ...
</footer>
<!-- Footer -->
</body>
 ...
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los que respondieron a mi pregunta, ya encontré la forma de que el footer se ajustará al pie de la pagina sin importar el contenido de la página.... Lo que hice fue encerrar lo que es el contenido principal de la página en un div con el ID de contenedor y colocando un código similar al que Isaí Pólito puso en la respuesta... dentro del css del contenedor puse un min-height:100vh; y con la funcion calc le reste los 100px de la altura del footer y los 80px del padding-top del navbar, con esto hace que el footer se quede siempre al piso y que se desplace cuando haya más contenido en la página y siempre en el pie de la pagina...
Este es el Código fuente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- Lllamado a las hojas de estilos CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../CSS/Bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../CSS/Administrador.css">
    <title>Administración</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Barra del menú -->
 <header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <nav class=" navbar navbar-default nav navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-1">
                        <span class="sr-only"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <img class="Imagen"src="../Imagenes/LOGO.png" alt="FYDBB">
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="">Empresa</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="">Ofertas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Ver Registros</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Cotizar</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                Seguridad
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="">Usuarios</a></li>
                                <li><a href="">Roles</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                Productos
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                               <li><a href="#">Familia#1</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">Familia#2</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">Familia#3</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">Familia#4</a></li>
                               <li class="divider"></li>
                               <li><a href="">Ver Productos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar artículo">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                            Ayuda
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="">Versión</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Ayuda</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
                                Cuenta
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                               <li><a href="">Ajustes</a></li>
                               <li><a href="">Cambiar contraseña</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div> 
</header>
<!-- Termina la barra del menú -->
<!-- Mensaje de bienvenida al usuario -->
<div id="contenedor">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="container" id="Mensaje">
        <h1>Administración de la página</h1>
    </div>
</div> 
<!-- Cuerpo de la pagina --> 
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <br>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <h3 class="list-group-item active">
                    Acciones
                    </h3>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        Dapibus ac facilisis in
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        Morbi leo risus
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        Porta ac consectetur ac
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                        Vestibulum at eros
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="bottom">

  <!-- Copyright -->
  <!-- <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2018 Copyright:
    <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
  </div> -->
  <!-- Copyright -->

</footer>
<!-- Footer -->
</body>
<!-- Sciripts para el uso de JQuery y Bootstrap -->
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</html>
```

Y este es el CSS:

```
    body{
    padding-top: 80px;
    background: url(../Imagenes/LOGO.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 450px;
    margin: 0px;
} 
#Mensaje{
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.Imagen{
    width: 220px;
}  
footer{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;

} 
#contenedor{
    min-height: calc(100vh - 100px - 80px);
}
```

Este truco lo descubrí gracias a un video de youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hK_v6FNIFK0&list=LLOfHpQ8DcKH94Xwks4BNE7Q&index=2&t=0s

Gracias por la ayuda!!!!!!

Comment: En realidad no era necesario dar tanta vuelta, con la clase `.fixed-bottom` que ya tenías en tu elemento `<footer>` bastaba. El problema es que en tu CSS estabas aplicando la propiedad `position: relative;` a dicho elemento. El problema no es de Bootstrap, hice pruebas con tu código sin añadir tu CSS personalizado y funciona como debería.